# In C++, can you compare templates the way you can compare types?

Tags: c++, c++14, variadic-templates, comparator, template-templates

I had an idea for a template comparator analogous to `std::is_same`. If two templates are the same, then at least their instantiations given template arguments will be the same.

```
template<template<class...> class LHS, template<class..> class RHS, class... S>
using is_same_template = std::is_same<LHS<S...>, RHS<S...>>::value;
```

Is there a way to compare `LHS` and `RHS` without `S...`? I believe that without `S...`, the comparator would have to be instantiated over `S...` anyway. If they were template functions instead, I would not expect to be able to compare them, I would need to compare their instantiations. Is my intuition correct?

Comment: Only instantiated templates are compiled, and you can't compare something that isn't compiled, so the only things you can compare are instances.

Comment: Actually, I think I figured it out. I'll try answering my question without marking it as correct, let me know what you think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the same approach you might take with types or values works for templates. The first two lines show usage with just templates, and don't require the `equals` or `tag` functions, or any arguments to the supplied templates. The second two extract the templates from values and perform the same tests on those.

```
#include <iostream>

template<class...> struct A {};
template<class...> struct B {};

template<template<class...> class S>
struct Tag;

template<template<class...> class S>
struct Tag {
    template<template<class...> class T>
    constexpr auto equals(Tag<T>) -> std::false_type { return {}; }
    constexpr auto equals(Tag<S>) -> std::true_type { return {}; }
};

template<template<class...> class T, class... V>
Tag<T> tag(T<V...> const&) { return {}; }

template<class S, class T>
auto equals(S && s, T && t) -> decltype(tag(s).equals(tag(t))) { return {}; }

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
    using namespace std;

    cout << Tag<A>{}.equals(Tag<A>{}) << "; " << Tag<A>{}.equals(Tag<B>{}) << endl;
    // 1; 0
    cout << Tag<B>{}.equals(Tag<A>{}) << "; " << Tag<B>{}.equals(Tag<B>{}) << endl;
    // 0; 1

    A<float> af;
    A<double> ad;
    B<int> bi;
    B<char, char> bcs;

    cout << equals(af, ad) << "; " << equals(af, bi) << endl;
    // 1; 0
    cout << equals(bi, ad) << "; " << equals(bi, bcs) << endl;
    // 0; 1

}
```

Answer (score 1):

> I had an idea for a template comparator analogous to std::is_same. [...] Is there a way to compare `LHS` and `RHS` without `S...`?

You can take inspiration from the "possible implementation" of `std::is_same` in [this page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_same) and write an analogous for template-template

```
template <template <typename ...> class, template <typename ...> class>
struct is_tpl_same : public std::false_type
 { };

template <template <typename ...> class C>
struct is_tpl_same<C, C> : public std::true_type
 { };
```

You can verify that

```
static_assert( true  == is_tpl_same<std::set, std::set>::value, "!" );
static_assert( false == is_tpl_same<std::vector, std::set>::value, "!" );
```